# VBA: Setting an object within a for loop, object stuck on first value

Tags: vba, excel, object, for-loop

I have some code that takes in a file path from a cell and reads the list of folders at the directory. I want it to do this in a loop for two cells (in my case B8 and B9). At the moment the code is looking at the first file path twice, rather than both paths once. The section of the code I believe is causing me the problem is here:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object


For k = 8 to 9
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox k
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("B" & k).Value)
    MsgBox objFolder
    'do the bit of code that reads the files    

Next
```

The first message box returns 8 & later 9 as expected, but MsgBox objFolder stays stuck on B8.value.
I feel like I need to be clearing objFolder by setting it to null or similar but have tried a few variations of this with no success.

**Update to provide more code in case I'm unwittingly doing something I shouldn't be:**

The whole thing reads in the file paths, finds a particular text file at the path, unzips it and then imports the text files into two tabs.

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Directory(15) As String
Dim ZIPFile As Variant


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
'moved to outside now

For k = 8 To 9


Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("B" & k).Value)
i = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
Directory(i) = objFile.Path
i = i + 1
Next objFile


For i = 0 To 14
If Right(Directory(i), 6) = "FQ.zip" Then ZIPFile = Directory(i)

Next

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim strDate As String

        DefPath = "Path name..."

        'Create the folder name
        strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
        FileNameFolder = DefPath & "MyUnzipFolder " & strDate & "\"


        MkDir FileNameFolder

        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        oApp.Namespace(Fname).items
Sheets(1).Range("F" & k).Value = Replace(Right(ZIPFile, 25), ".zip", "") & "\EL-contract-rg.txt"

        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
         oApp.Namespace(ZIPFile).items.Item(Replace(Right(ZIPFile, 26), ".zip", "") & "\EL-contract-rg.txt")

        MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True



Sheets(k - 6).Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
         "TEXT;" & FileNameFolder & "EL-contract-rg.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With



 Next



End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve your issue, but `Set objFSO` should **not** be done inside that loop.

Comment: Unable to replicate, even using your code as-is. Are you sure that B8 and B9 actually contain different values?

Comment: If I can't set it within the loop does that mean I can't set it to be two different things? i.e. i should just paste out the content of the loop twice for two sets of objects, one where k = 8 and one where k = 9?

Comment: `objFSO` is not set to "two different things", it's one object, a Scripting.FileSystemObject class.

Comment: `objFolder` *can and should* be set within the loop.  `objFSO` should not be.

Comment: you need to move the set objFSO outside of the for loop.  You can also set objFolder = Nothing at the end of the for loop which should release the object.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I misread initially as objFolder where you said objFSO. B8 and B9 are definitely different.

Comment: @Sorceri doesn't make a difference, but yes that's a good recommendation.

Comment: I can reproduce this if I use `On Error Resume Next` and the folder in B9 doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kyle good observation!  So perhaps OP has not provided all the relevant code :)

Comment: I definitely haven't because it works fine for me taken as I've posted it, I will post some more

Comment: Does it work "fine", or does it not work? Which is it??

Comment: In my full code the problem exists. When I create a new sheet and add just the piece of code I posted, the problem does not exist.

Comment: You use `On Error Resume Next` and never reset error handling. Underneath `For k = 8 To 9` Put `On Error GoTo 0` and let us know what happens.

Comment: You've nailed it. "Path not found". Thank you very much. I was going so screen blind I didn't even remember that I had an On Error in there when you originally mentioned it.

Comment: Strangely, while B8 gets found + used and B9 says "not found", I observe the same behaviour when I swap B8 and B9's values around. i.e. they're both working paths

Comment: Try fully qualifying `Range("B" & k).Value` with the worksheet name.

Comment: That's it! Thanks again, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

This works as-expected, incidentally, your code also works as expected and does not exhibit the problem you describe in OP.

@Kyle has identified a possible cause of this problem, which would be improper error-handling with `On Error Resume Next` which will exhibit this failure of the specified folder path doesn't exist.

`On Error Resume Next` is the Devil's work, unless you know how to use it locally and trap errors.  It is generally preferable to anticipate errors and code for those exceptions, like below, where we use the `.FolderExists` method of the FSO class to handle what would otherwise be a runtime error:

```
Sub foo()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For k = 8 To 9
    If objFSO.FolderExists(Range("B" & k).Value) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("B" & k).Value)
        Debug.Print k & vbTab & objFolder
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]